# How to change for-loop iterator variable in the loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to know if is it possible to change the value of the iterator in its for-loop?

For example I want to write a program to calculate prime factor of a number in the below way :

```
def primeFactors(number):
    for i in range(2,number+1):
        if (number%i==0)
            print(i,end=',')
            number=number/i 
            i=i-1 #to check that factor again!
```

My question : Is it possible to change the last two line in a way that when I change `i` and `number` in the `if` block, their value change in the `for` loop!

Update: Defining the iterator as a `global` variable, could help me? Why?

Comment: I expect someone will answer with code for what you said you want to do, but the short answer is "no"... when you change the value of `number` it does not change the value here: `range(2,number+1)` because this is an expression that has already been evaluated and has returned a list of numbers which is being looped over

Comment: Nope, not with what you have written here.  There are ways, but they'd be tricky to say the least.

Comment: Use a while loop instead. (Uglier but works for what you're trying to do.)

Comment: There has been some discussion on the python-ideas list about a `continue with` statement to allow injection back into the iterator, but it is fairly simple to code a custom wrapper around an iterator that allows such behavior already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer (like Daniel Roseman's): No

Long answer: No, but this does what you want:

```
def redo_range(start, end):
    while start < end:
        start += 1
        redo = (yield start)
        if redo:
            start -= 2

redone_5 = False
r = redo_range(2, 10)
for i in r:
    print(i)
    if i == 5 and not redone_5:
        r.send(True)
        redone_5 = True
```

Output:

```
3
4
5
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

As you can see, `5` gets repeated. It used a generator function which allows the last value of the index variable to be repeated. There are simpler methods (`while` loops, list of values to check, etc.) but this one matches you code the closest.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Python's `for` loop is like other languages' `foreach` loops. Your `i` variable is not a counter, it is the value of each element in a list, in this case the list of numbers between 2 and number+1. Even if you changed the value, that would not change what was the next element in that list.

Comment: defining that iterator as a `global` variable couldn't help me? I remember it was possible in C++ to change the value of for-loop iterator in its block!

Comment: @TheGoodUser : Please try to avoid modifying globals: there's almost always a better way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of dealing with this is to completely exhaust the divisions by `i` in the body of the `for` loop itself:

```
def primeFactors(number):
    for i in range(2,number+1):
        while number % i == 0:
            print(i, end=',')
            number /= i
```

It's slightly more efficient to do the division and remainder in one step:

```
def primeFactors(number):
    for i in range(2, number+1):
        while True:
            q, r = divmod(number, i)
            if r != 0:
                break
            print(i, end=',')
            number = q
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to change the next value yielded is to somehow tell the iterable what the next value to yield *should be*.  With a lot of standard iterables, **this isn't possible**.  however, you can do it with a specially coded generator:

```
def crazy_iter(iterable):
  iterable = iter(iterable)
  for item in iterable:
    sent = yield item
    if sent is not None:
      yield None  # Return value of `iterable.send(...)`
      yield sent

num = 10
iterable = crazy_iter(range(2, 11))
for i in iterable:
  if not num%i:
    print i
    num /= i
    if i > 2:
      iterable.send(i-1)
```

I would definitely not argue that this is easier to read than the equivalent `while` loop, but it does demonstrate sending stuff to a generator which may gain your team points at your next local programming trivia night.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible the way you are doing it. The *for loop variable* **can** be changed **inside** each loop iteration, like this:

```
for a in range (1, 6):
    print a
    a = a + 1
    print a
    print
```

The resulting output is:

```
1
2

2
3

3
4

4
5

5
6
```

It **does** get modified inside each *for loop* iteration.

The reason for the behavior displayed by Python's *for loop* is that, at the beginning of each iteration, the *for loop variable* is assinged the **next** unused value from the ***specified iterator***. Therefore, whatever changes you make to the *for loop variable* get effectively destroyed at the beginning of each iteration.

To achieve what I think you may be needing, you should probably use a *while loop*, providing your own *counter* variable, your own increment code and any special case modifications for it you may need inside your loop. Example:

```
a = 1
while a <= 5:
    print a
    if a == 3:
        a = a + 1
    a = a + 1
    print a
    print
```

The resulting output is:

```
1
2

2
3

3
5

5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can only if we dont change the reference of the object that we are using. If we can edit the number by accessing the reference of number variable, then what you asked is possible.

A simple example:

```
a=[1,2,3]
a=a+[4]==>here, a new object is created which plots to different address.
a+=[4]==>here , the same object is getting updated which give us the desired result.



number=10
list1=list(range(2,number+1))
# list1   
for i in list1:
    print(list1,i)
    if (number%i==0):
        print(i,end=',')
        number=number//i #we can simply replace it with number//=i to edit the number without changing the reference or without creating a new object.
        try:
            [list1.pop() for i in range(10,0,-1) if(i>number)]
             #here pop() method is working on the same object which list created by number refers. so, we can able to change the iterable in the forloop. 

        except:
            continue
        i=i-1 #to check that factor again!
```